# Windows Phone - Using ContextMenu for Images in a WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a wrap panel that is populated with Image controls at run time. I want to use a context menu to remove images I want to delete.

```
            <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="wrap_Panel">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="false" x:Name="ContextMenu" >
                        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Delete" Header="Delete" Click="DeleteImage"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

This allows me to get the menu up but how do I actually delete the image I pressed?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DeleteImage( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if ( menuItem != null )
    {
      Image imageItem = menuItem.DataContext as Image;
...
```

find the imageItem in your collection or list and delete it.

Comment: I tried to use wrap_Panel.Children.Remove(imageItem); but it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to get the index of element,  `int index = wrap_Panel.Children.IndexOf(imageItem);` is there something real (control can find the imageItem)?

Comment: How do you create and add the images on the WrapPanel? Show your code.